# Lockscreen is missing

Tags: android, lockscreen

Following behaviour:

1. My App is in foreground
2. Display is going off
3. I turn the display on
4. Lockscreen (to enter pin code) isn't there! Instead App is still in foreground

Is there a problem with reciver or services? Had anybody the same problem? It's not all the time, sometimes the Lockscreen is available... 
I've got a Nexus S with android 4.1.2 and the App has minSdkVersion 14 and targetSdkVersion 18

Answer (score 0):

You should call the lockscreen activity under onResume() in your Mainactivity. For an example

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startActivity(PasscodeLockActivity.class);  //PasscodeLockActivity is your LockScreen Activity
}
```

Comment: ah, sorry, I mean the lockscreen from the OS to enter pin or pattern. Not an Activity writen by myself.

Comment: :o :o is this the right place to ask functionality issue :D ??

Comment: don't know, tell me the right place ;) I don't know for what and where I have to search...

Comment: it depends upon your lock settings. just wait for a min even after the display gone....and then check it will ask for the passcode :D

Comment: no it won't! That's the problem. sometimes I wait for 5, 10 mins and it doesn't appear. But only when the app I'm developing is in foreground. And not each time. I don't know what's the reason...